# Not downloading converted OSGI bundles from custom p2 site using Maven

Tags: maven

My project is in RCP. The product is created using Maven. My RCP project depends on third party jars. Currently we are adding these jars in plugin.xml "runtime". So whenever there is change in third party jars, we have to update the plugin.xml file. 
Now we are changing the process by converting the third party jars in to OSGI bundle using maven then create p2 site and while building, add the third party OSGI bundles in classpath. 
We have done the conversion to OSGI bundle and creating p2 site. But when we are adding it in repository, the converted third party OSGI bundles are not always get download. 
We have added below code in pom.xml to convert in to OSGI bundle and create p2:site:

```
  <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.reficio</groupId>
                        <artifactId>p2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>default-cli</id>
                                <configuration>
                                    <artifacts>
                                      <artifact><id>com.test.proj:proj-jar1:6.01.00-SNAPSHOT</id></artifact>
                                        <artifact><id>com.test.proj:proj-jar2:6.01.00-SNAPSHOT</id></artifact>
                                        <artifact><id>com.test.proj:proj-jar3:1.1</id></artifact>
                                        <artifact><id>com.test.proj:proj-jar4:1.0</id></artifact>
                                        <artifact><id>com.test.proj:proj-jar5:1.0</id></artifact>
                                        <artifact><id>com.test.proj:proj-jar6:6.01.00-SNAPSHOT</id></artifact>
                                    </artifacts>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>

                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>8.1.5.v20120716</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
                            <webAppSourceDirectory>${basedir}/target/repository/</webAppSourceDirectory>
                            <webApp>
                                <contextPath>/site</contextPath>
                            </webApp>
                       </configuration>
                    </plugin>
            <plugin>  
               <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>  
               <artifactId>tycho-maven-plugin</artifactId>  
               <version>0.22.0</version>
               <extensions>false</extensions>
            </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
            <pluginRepositories>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <id>reficio</id>
                    <url>http://repo.reficio.org/maven/</url>
                </pluginRepository>
            </pluginRepositories>
```

To download while build we have added:

```
<repositories>
        <repository>
                <id>extJars</id>
                <url>http://localhost:8080/site/</url>
                <layout>p2</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

When we call "mvn install" it is not downloading the jars from "http://localhost:8080/site" every time. 
So please let me know what is going wrong in my pom.xml

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Beceause Maven does not work this way. You need two steps where you 1.) build the p2 update site for your 3rd party stuff and 2.) build the rest of the system. In m2e they are using something they call **wrapper bundles** which are OSGI plugins which hold the jars and exports them. Take a look in the m2e GitHub repo for this.

Comment: So use the `maven-bundle-plugin` in another plugin which holds the jars and exports them.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Can you please explain me in detail.

Comment: I made an answer out of it giving you a pointer on how it is used.

Comment: If my answer answered the question you can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

In Maven you cannot build something and then depend on it dynamically in one reactor. This way the build dependencies cannot be computed. You either have to

1. Build your p2 update site
2. Build the rest

or you should use something the m2e people call [**wrapper bundle**](https://twitter.com/jvanzyl/status/486576717956263936). They [used it in this pom.xml](https://github.com/eclipse/m2e-core/blob/master/m2e-maven-runtime/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.indexer/pom.xml).